# Comparing Lists of Strings in Scala

Tags: string, list, scala

I know lists are immutable but I'm still confused on how I would go about this. I have two lists of strings -  For example:

```
var list1: List[String] = List("M", "XW1", "HJ", "K")
var list2: List[String] = List("M", "XW4", "K", "YN")
```

I want to loop through these lists and see if the elements match. If it doesn't, the program would immediately return `false`. If it is a match, it will continue to iterate until it finds an element that begins with `X`. If it is indeed an `X`, I want to return `true` regardless of whether the number is the same or not.

Problem I'm having is that currently I have a conditional stating that if the two elements do not match, return `false` immediately. This is a problem because obviously `XW1` and `XW4` are not the same and it will return false. How can I bypass this and determine that it is a match to my eyes regardless of the number?

I also have a counter a two length variables to account for the fact the lists may be of differing length. My counter goes up to the shortest list: `for (x <- 0 to (c-1))` (c being the counter).

Comment: What do you expect the result of provided sample list1 and list2?

Comment: This example should return true.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `zipAll` & `forall`.

```
def compareLists(l1: List[String], l2: List[String]): Boolean =
  l1.zipAll(l2, "", "").forall {
    case (x, y) =>
      (x == y) || (x.startsWith("X") && y.startsWith("X"))
  }
```

Note that I am assuming an empty string will always be different than any other element.

Comment: this is not what he expect I guess! This solution returns false for given inputs but expected is true

Comment: @PritamKadam so, let me see if I understood correctly. You start checking that each pair of elements are the same, if they are not the same and they both do not start with an `X` then return **false**, if they both start with an `X` return **true**. If one list is smaller than the other return **false**. If all pairs were equal and we never found a pair whose elements started with `X` we also return **true**. If two elements are the same but they both start with `X` return **true**.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement correctly, to be considered a match, 1) each element in the same position of the two lists being simultaneously iterated must be the same except when both start with `X` (in which case it should return `true` without comparing any further), and 2) both lists must be of the same size.

If that's correct, I would recommend using a simple recursive function like below:

```
def compareLists(ls1: List[String], ls2: List[String]): Boolean = (ls1, ls2) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) =>
    true
  case (h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2) =>
    if (h1.startsWith("X") && h2.startsWith("X"))
      true  // short-circuiting
    else
      if (h1 != h2)
        false
      else
        compareLists(t1, t2)
  case _ =>
    false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that, result should be true for lists given in question, you could do something like this:

```scala
val list1: List[String] = List("M", "XW1", "HJ", "K")
val list2: List[String] = List("M", "XW4", "K", "YN")


val (matched, unmatched) = list1.zipAll(list2, "", "").partition { case (x, y) => x == y }

val result = unmatched match {
  case Nil         => true
  case (x, y) :: _ => (x.startsWith("X") && y.startsWith("X"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use cats `foldM` to iterate through the lists and terminate early if there is either (a) a mismatch, or (b) two elements that begin with 'X':

```
import cats.implicits._

val list1: List[String] = List("M", "XW1", "HJ", "K")
val list2: List[String] = List("M", "XW4", "K", "YN")

list1.zip(list2).foldM(()){
  case (_, (s1, s2)) if s1 == s2 => ().asRight
  case (_, (s1, s2)) if s1.startsWith("X") && s2.startsWith("X") => true.asLeft
  case _ => false.asLeft
}.left.getOrElse(false)
```